# syslog-ng make error - final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on out

Tags: syslog-ng

I am trying to install syslog-ng-3.13.2 from source code on embedded linux. I executed **./configure --with-ivykis=system** successfully. After that, on executing **make**, I get the following error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/4.9.4/../../../../aarch64-fsl-linux/bin/ld:
>   /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)(.text+0x76'
>   /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-fsl-linux/4.9.4/../../../../aarch64-fsl-linux/bin/ld:
>   final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on out collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [lib/libsyslog-ng.la] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make: *** [all] Error 2

libcrypto.a is present in /usr/local/lib directory.
How do I resolve this error?

**UPDATE**: As suggested in the comments, I am putting the output of `./configure`:

```
./configure --with-ivykis=system
Script started on 2018-01-17 12:46:09+0000
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether UID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... none needed
checking whether yytext is a pointer... no
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/aarch64-fsl-linux/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/aarch64-fsl-linux/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/aarch64-fsl-linux/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/aarch64-fsl-linux/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for shl_load... no
checking for shl_load in -ldld... no
checking for dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking whether a program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether a statically linked program can dlopen itself... yes
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking CFLAGS_NOWARN_POINTER_SIGN for gcc -Wno-pointer-sign... -Wno-pointer-sign
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking how to enable static linking for certain libraries... GNU or Solaris
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking dmalloc.h usability... no
checking dmalloc.h presence... no
checking for dmalloc.h... no
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking getopt.h usability... yes
checking getopt.h presence... yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking stropts.h usability... yes
checking stropts.h presence... yes
checking for stropts.h... yes
checking sys/strlog.h usability... no
checking sys/strlog.h presence... no
checking for sys/strlog.h... no
checking door.h usability... no
checking door.h presence... no
checking for door.h... no
checking sys/capability.h usability... no
checking sys/capability.h presence... no
checking for sys/capability.h... no
checking sys/prctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/prctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/prctl.h... yes
checking utmp.h usability... yes
checking utmp.h presence... yes
checking for utmp.h... yes
checking utmpx.h usability... yes
checking utmpx.h presence... yes
checking for utmpx.h... yes
checking tcpd.h usability... no
checking tcpd.h presence... no
checking for tcpd.h... no
checking for struct ucred... yes
checking for struct cmsgcred... no
checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
checking for SO_ACCEPTCONN... yes
checking for struct tm.tm_gmtoff... yes
checking for struct msghdr.msg_control... yes
checking for I_CONSLOG... yes
checking for O_LARGEFILE... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_storage... yes
checking for struct sockaddr_in6... yes
checking for PR_SET_KEEPCAPS... yes
checking for modern utmp... yes
checking for door_create in -ldoor... no
checking for socket in -lsocket... no
checking for nanosleep in -lrt... yes
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... yes
checking for regexec in -lregex... no
checking for res_init in -lresolv... no
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for strtoimax... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for getnameinfo... yes
checking for getutent... yes
checking for getutxent... yes
checking for pread... yes
checking for pwrite... yes
checking for strcasestr... yes
checking for memrchr... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking for gmtime_r... yes
checking for strtok_r... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for inotify_init... yes
checking for TCP wrapper library... 
checking whether to enable TCP wrapper support... no
checking for dlsym in -ldl... yes
checking for LIBDBI... no
checking for dbi_initialize_r in -ldbi... no
checking whether to enable SQL support... no
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for g_mapped_file_unref... yes
checking for g_list_copy_deep... yes
checking sanity checking Glib headers... yes
checking for GEOIP... no
checking for MAXMINDDB... checking for MMDB_open in -lmaxminddb... no
checking for PCRE... yes
checking for OPENSSL... yes
checking whether SSL_CTX_get0_param is declared... yes
checking whether X509_STORE_CTX_get0_cert is declared... no
checking whether X509_get_extension_flags is declared... no
checking whether EVP_MD_CTX_reset is declared... no
checking whether ASN1_STRING_get0_data is declared... no
checking whether DH_set0_pqg is declared... no
checking for LIBNET... no
checking whether to enable spoof source support... no
checking for CRITERION... no
configure: WARNING: pkg-config was not able to find Criterion >= 2.2.1
checking for IVYKIS... yes
checking for JSON... configure: WARNING: Internal jsonc sources not found in lib/jsonc
no
checking for prop_get in -lsasl2... no
checking for libESMTP... no
checking for libcurl... no
checking for HIREDIS... no
configure: WARNING: pkg-config was not able to find hiredis >= 0.11.0
checking for HIREDIS... no
configure: WARNING: pkg-config was not able to find libhiredis >= 0.11.0
checking for RIEMANN_CLIENT... no
checking for PYTHON... no
checking for PYTHON... no
checking for PYTHON... no
checking for JAVA_VERSION... no
configure: WARNING: Could not build Java modules without Java
checking whether to enable Sun STREAMS support... no
checking whether to enable IPv6 support... yes
checking whether to enable Linux capability support... no
checking whether to enable mongodb destination support... yes
checking whether to enable amqp destination support... yes
checking for libsystemd... no
checking for libsystemd_daemon... no
checking for LIBSYSTEMD_JOURNAL... no
checking for UUID... yes
checking for struct tm.tm_zone... yes
checking for `timezone' variable in time.h... yes
checking for `altzone' variable in time.h... no
checking for `daylight' variable in time.h... yes
checking whether to enable Valgrind on the unit tests... checking for valgrind... no
yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating syslog-ng-native-connector.pc
config.status: creating dist.conf
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating syslog-ng.spec
config.status: creating syslog-ng.pc
config.status: creating syslog-ng-add-contextual-data.pc
config.status: creating libtest/syslog-ng-test.pc
config.status: creating scripts/update-patterndb
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing syslog-ng-config.h commands
config.status: creating syslog-ng-config.h - prefix SYSLOG_NG for config.h defines
config.status: syslog-ng-config.h is unchanged
=== configuring in lib/ivykis (/syslog-ng-3.13.2/lib/ivykis)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure.gnu --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  '--with-ivykis=system' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
=== configuring in modules/afmongodb/mongo-c-driver (/syslog-ng-3.13.2/modules/afmongodb/mongo-c-driver)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure.gnu --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  '--with-ivykis=system' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
=== configuring in modules/afamqp/rabbitmq-c (/syslog-ng-3.13.2/modules/afamqp/rabbitmq-c)
configure: running /bin/sh ./configure.gnu --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  '--with-ivykis=system' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
syslog-ng Open Source Edition 3.13.2 configured
Edition settings:
Release type                : stable
Pretty version              : 3
Combined vers.              : 3 (3.13.2)
Package name                : syslog-ng
Compiler options:
compiler                    : gcc -std=gnu99
compiler options            : -g -O2 -Wall -pthread  -pthread -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I$(top_srcdir)/lib/eventlog/src -I$(top_builddir)/lib/eventlog/src -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include   -I/usr/local/include -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
linker flags                :  
prefix                      : /usr/local
linking mode                : dynamic
embedded crypto             : no
__thread keyword            : yes
Test dependencies:
Criterion                   : no
Submodules:
ivykis                      : system
mongoc                      : internal
librabbitmq                 : internal
jsonc                       : internal
Features:
Forced server mode          : yes
Debug symbols               : no
GCC profiling               : no
Memtrace                    : no
IPV6 support                : yes
spoof-source support        : no
tcp-wrapper support         : no
Linux capability support    : no
Env wrapper support         : no
systemd support             : no (unit dir: none)
systemd-journal support     : optional
libmongo-client options     : yes
Modules:
Module search path          : ${exec_prefix}/lib/syslog-ng
Sun STREAMS support (module): no
SQL support (module)        : auto
PACCT module (EXPERIMENTAL) : no
MongoDB destination (module): yes
JSON support (module)       : no
SMTP support (module)       : no
HTTP support (module)       : no
AMQP destination (module)   : yes
STOMP destination (module)  : yes
GEOIP support (module)      : no
GEOIP2 support (module)     : no
Redis support (module)      : no
Riemann destination (module): no, microseconds: no
python                      : no (pkg-config package: auto)
java                        : no
java modules                : no
native bindings             : auto
Script done on 2018-01-17 12:46:21+0000
```

Comment: As it seems to be some sort of custom build of Linux could you list "packages list"  you have installed and maybe the result of your ` configure` command, it's very unlikely someone will be able to help with such a short yet precise information. By the way a short check on google shows that your problem could either be from a missing library or an incompatible version of GCC or anything like that

Comment: @Kiwy : As suggested by you, I have updated the post with the configure output.